# How to change an old z3::expr(Oldvec) to a new z3::expr(Vec)?

Tags: c++, z3

I want to change an Old z3::expr(Oldvec) like this:

```
OldVec is:(and (= (= R4 0) true) (= (= R6 R7) true))
```

To a new z3::expr(Vec) like this:

```
Vec is:(and (= (= R4 0) false) (= (= R6 R7) true))
```

I have tried to change a string to z3::expr like this:

```
void changeZ3(z3::expr &OldVec) {
    std::string s="(set-info :status unknown)\n"
                  "(declare-fun R4 () Int)\n"
                  "(declare-fun R7 () Int)\n"
                  "(declare-fun R6 () Int)\n"
                  "(assert\n"
                  " (= (= R4 0) false))\n"
                  "(assert\n"
                  " (= (= R6 R7) true))\n"
                  "(check-sat)";
    std::cout<<"OldVec is:"<<OldVec<<"\n";
    z3::expr Vec=C.parse_string(s.data());
    std::cout<<"Vec is:"<<Vec<<"\n";
    OldVec=Vec;
}
```

I have printed Oldvec and Vec,they are looked same:

```
OldVec is:(and (= (= R4 0) true) (= (= R6 R7) true))    
Vec is:(and (= (= R4 0) false) (= (= R6 R7) true))
```

After `changeZ3` returned,I did `Solver.add(Vec)` like this:

```
z3::expr Vec = Ctx.parse_file(FormulaFile); //FormulaFile save z3::expr which looked like "s" on the top|^    
changeZ3(Vec);
Solver.add(Vec);
```

and then I got an exception when I do `Solver.add(Vec)` like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'z3::exception'
```

Why did this happened? Is there other way to change a z3::expr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the call to `parse_file` needs to be told what the sorts and declarations are that are in the scope. That is, while you successfully constructed the "expression" in `Vec`, you still have to insert into the context the sort `Int` and the declarations for `R4`, `R7`, and `R6`.

This is a common gotcha in z3 programming: You have to keep in mind that the `Ctx` must be appropriately set up for these formulas to "make sense" when you call `Solver.add`.

In general, you should shy away from "parsing" strings like this and adding them to the solver. Instead, you should work in the context that you have and directly create the expressions using the expression AST.